# clang-format doesn't recognize matching header's name

Tags: c++, clang-format

I have a `.clang-format` file configured, where I want to do the following sorting

```cpp
#include <stdafx.h>

#include "the_header_of_this_source_file.h"

#include <includes_with_arrow>

#include "includes_with_quote.h"
```

So far, I have this configuration

```yaml
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           'stdafx.h'
    Priority:        -2
  - Regex:           '^[<|"].*Prototypes.h'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^<.*>'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '^".*"'
    Priority:        3
IncludeIsMainRegex: '$'
IncludeIsMainSourceRegex: ''
```

but when formatting the code, it moves `the_header_of_this_source_file.h` into the `quote` group (assuming the header is included with quotes), leading me to the following result

```cpp
#include <stdafx.h>

#include <includes_with_arrow>

// Sorted in alphabetical order
#include "includes_with_quote.h"
#include "the_header_of_this_source_file.h"
```

How do I prevent this behavior?

### Edit

As I understand, the reason comes from the fact, that the header of the file matches the pattern `^".*"`, therefore its priority is changed. So, maybe there is a way to ignore pattern matching for the main header?

Comment: Worked for me when I formatted `the_header_of_this_source_file.cpp`.

Comment: Have you tried reordering the rules from more general to more specific?

Comment: @KrzysiekKarbowiak I have no rule for the main header itself, so whatever matches it, either more generic or specific, it will be ordered by that group. And by the snippet I provided, at least `'^".*"'` matches the main header (I don't include the main header in `<>`s)

Comment: Are you sure you're using the .clang-format file? Invokation must literally include `--style=file` and be invoked in the same directory as the file, or a child directory thereof.

Comment: @lionkor I am, because modifying a specific property causes a different formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In my project I have something like this:

```
IncludeBlocks: Regroup
IncludeCategories:
  - Regex:           'set_nod.h|stdafx.h'
    Priority:        -1
  - Regex:           '^"'
    Priority:        1
  - Regex:           '(projectDir1|projectDir2|projectDir3)'
    Priority:        2
  - Regex:           '(someDep1|someDep2)'
    Priority:        3
  - Regex:           '.*'
    Priority:        4
```

And it works for me as desired. Didn't had to investigate how to force matching header file - it just worked.

Also consider trashing `IncludeIsMainRegex` and `IncludeIsMainSourceRegex`. Default value should do the work. If I understand documentation correctly those properties are controlling matching source file with respective header file. They allow to handle suffixes in the filenames.

[Doc says](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) that `''` means "arbitrary suffix" (I ready this as "any suffix") and I think `IncludeIsMainSourceRegex` is entry which is screwing your configuration. Drop this value or set it to `'$'`.

Comment: Do you have `IncludeBlocks: Regroup`?

Comment: On one of my personal [projects](https://github.com/arsdever/opengl_tutorials/) it also works. But in the project at my job, it doesn't.

Comment: Yes `IncludeBlocks: Regroup` is used (updated the answer). No other `Include*` are present in my configuration file.

Comment: Maybe problem is version of clang? If not then edit your question and post whole content of clang format configuration file.

Comment: So, the version in my personal project is `12.0.0` (windows), which is not available on brew repo (macos 13.0.1 available). Not sure if there is a bug on the new version about this.

Comment: @arsdever see update of answer I'm pretty sure `IncludeIsMainSourceRegex` is a problem.

Comment: as you see in the example in the question, it was already set to `'$'`. The main point here to threat as a potential issue is the version. I'll try version `13.0.1` later on windows machine and see if the issue persists.